# How to call Python Methods from Mathematica employing ExternalEvaluate?

Tags: python, external-calls

This question is about the compatibility of methods written in Python and [ExternalEvaluate](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExternalEvaluate.html) from Mathematica.

ExternalEvaluate allows Python functions to be called from Mathematica. For example, the function "surfaceArea" from sphere.py:

```python
from math import pi
def surfaceArea(r):
    return 4*pi*r**2
```

may be called from Mathematica in the following way

```
pySession = StartExternalSession["Python"];
ExternalEvaluate[pySession, File["sphere.py"]];
radius = 2.0;
ExternalEvaluate[pySession, "surfaceArea" -> {radius}]
```

Now, consider the [sphere Python class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540225/simple-class-in-python) (sphereClass.py)

```python
from math import pi
class sphere(object):

    def __init__(self,radius):
        self.radius = radius

    def volume(self):
        return (4/3)*pi*self.radius**3
```

**Aim**: Evaluate volume from sphereClass.py at radius = 2.0 employing ExternalEvaluate.

Comment: What have you tried, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: There are diffrent ways to pass Mathematica data to python, one of the easiest one is `ExternalEvaluate[s, "sp = sphere(" <> ExportString[radius, "PythonExpression"] <> ");sp.volume()"]`, which outputs `33.5103`.

Comment: Is s equal to StartExternalSession["Python"] or is it something different? @BenyIzd

Comment: yes `s` is your `pySession`. @user10181864

Comment: It works. You should submit an answer @BenyIzd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to send Mathematica data to python, here you'll see direct string manipulation:

#### Initial code

```
pySession = StartExternalSession["Python"];
ExternalEvaluate[pySession, "from math import pi
class sphere(object):

    def __init__(self,radius):
        self.radius = radius

    def volume(self):
        return (4/3)*pi*self.radius**3"];

radius = 2.0;
```

#### Passing data

```
ExternalEvaluate[pySession, 
 "sp1=sphere(" <> ExportString[radius, "PythonExpression"] <> 
  ");sp1.volume()"]

(*Out: 33.5103*)
```

Or you can make it more readable by using `StringForm`:

```
ExternalEvaluate[pySession, 
 ToString@StringForm["sp2=sphere(``);sp2.volume()", 
   ExportString[radius, "PythonExpression"]]]

(*Out: 33.5103*)
```

#### finaly

Stop the session:

```
DeleteObject[pySession]
```